# Which is preferred for mapping values: reusing mapping functions OR building reference tables to do lookups?

Tags: python, sql, r, sas, database-optimization

## Which is preferred for mapping values: reusing mapping functions OR building reference tables to do lookups?

This is a very general high-level question, which, *I believe* is mostly language-independent. For the example, I will use `SAS`, but I also would like to know how people feel about this in `R` and `python`.

I am on a team that likes to use mapping functions to take an input and generate some output, usually in a one-to-one manner. For example, here is some modified SAS code that shows what my team typically does:

```
proc fcmp;
    function mapFunction($ input);
        output = .;
        if input= "Day zero" then output= 0;
            else if input = "Day one" then output = 1;
            else if input = "Day two" then output = 2;
        return(output);
    endsub;
run;
```

The team would then use `mapFunction` in multiple other programs when mapping needs to be done.

**This goes against my instinct.** My instinct would be to use the mapping function once to generate a set of key:value pairs or a dictionary or two-column table and thereafter use lookup/indexing/joining/merging operations to refer to the table.

I have a hard time explaining why this is my instinct, but it is. It *feels* better to have a reference table instead of calling a custom function repeatedly. However, I don't trust my *feelings*, and I'd like to hear from others to see if I can rationalize one technique over the other.

#### Can someone provide arguments/counter-arguments to support one technique or the other?

Thank you!

Comment: If the number of values is *low* and *stable* implementing a SQL UDF using CASE is a good idea, **if** the DBMS handles that without additional overhead, i.e. simply replaces the function call with the CASE expression.

Answer (score 2):

I've done a lot of conversions, which involve re-mapping codes. Your situation may be a little different. Conversions being one-off events, rather than on-going transformations like overnight DW refreshes.

The default position is to use a table, as you suggest. It has a real benefit in that a) you can query data to check for non-existent values in the map before you convert; b) the responsibility goes back to the business to confirm the code mappings are correct.

It gets trickier where the business rules for the conversion are in flux. For example, your first cut might provide a simple map, but the someone says 'except for these codes, where you need to look up an extra value' and suddenly you need a function. At that point, you need to revisit the code base to find where the mapped table is used and update to a function. That can be a lesson learned, depending on the size of the code base.

I have used functions to wrap the use of a mapping table. If you don't know which code is going to be problematic in a month's time, this can be useful. Function just selects a value from a mapping table as you would do in a join. It will be slower to execute but if you're optimizing programmer hours rather than execution time then that works. In any case, you get the data visibility from the code map as well as flexibility for scope-creep from the function. When the scope changes, just update the function.

When you say 'multiple other programs', sounds like a red flag. If you store the data in mapping tables, would the database in which they are stored be visible to these programs? That would be a consideration, big one.

Answer (score 2):

What's your evaluation criteria?

Are you looking for:

- program run time
- developer coding time
- usability
- ease of maintenance

Different people prioritize different things. The one good thing about the table method is that it's generic, simple and makes sense in almost any language. But...that does not mean it's the best for that language. How each language implements things under the hood will affect the criteria above.

In SAS, I would rarely use FCMP, but Formats are one of the fastest ways there and really have a table behind it that can be easily updated, so that would be my choice in SAS. It's slightly slower than the HASH and SET+KEY methods but it's easier to use and maintain and those end up saving more time in the long run. And I prioritize human time over computer time for 99% of my projects.

If you search on lexjansen.com you'll find many papers on the different ways to do look ups and a comparison of their run times. https://www.lexjansen.com/phuse/2007/cs/CS06.pdf

Comment: I agree- formats seem ideal for the kind of example given if you're working in SAS. And if you ever need to convert to another language, it's not hard to export formats to a lookup table.